# Mobile OWASP Security

Tags: android

I am doing an assignment to design an App that communicates with my rails server, I have completed the OWASP top 10 for rails side, but I was wondering for my App that talks to my SOAP APIs at rails server, what security should I implement? I have read about OWASP Mobile Security, but I am not sure, I know basic HTTPS is a must but I was wondering if there is any other suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You might find some helpful guidance from our free [Secure Mobile Development Best Practices](https://books.nowsecure.com/secure-mobile-development/en/index.html) resource, a collection of 50+ tips to help you learn how to develop secure Android and iOS apps.

Specifically, the practice [Implement Secure Network Transmission Of Sensitive Data](https://books.nowsecure.com/secure-mobile-development/en/sensitive-data/implement-secure-network-transmission-of-sensitive-data.html) might help you.

Disclosure: I'm Content Marketing Manager at NowSecure

Answer (score 0):

The OWASP mobile security project has alot more things than the "basic HTTPS is a must", for example about that topic, you can read more here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning

Going a little bit deeper in the project, you'll find this: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Android_Testing_Cheat_Sheet it contains a Step by Step example.

You can check again the **OWASP Mobile Security Project 2016**, they have a final release (2016) for the mobile version here:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Mobile_Security_Project (Main page)

and also the checklist: (*i dont know why, but is hosted on google drive, link from owasp site on top*).

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxOPagp1jPHWYmg3Y3BfLVhMcmc/view

Of course, they also have a **RC for the top 10 mobile** security project:

```
   M1 - Improper Platform Usage

   M2 - Insecure Data Storage

   M3 - Insecure Communication

   M4 - Insecure Authentication

   M5 - Insufficient Cryptography

   M6 - Insecure Authorization

   M7 - Client Code Quality

   M8 - Code Tampering

   M9 - Reverse Engineering

   M10 - Extraneous Functionality
```

The whole info about the mobile top ten is here: 
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Mobile_Top_10_2016-Top_10

Your app will be "safe" if you follow and learn about all this topics.